# Prototype JS Issues on Live Magento Site

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs, element

After some desperate assistance regarding prototype.js on Magento.

Please see the below product page on a live Magento website...

http://www.showermania.co.uk/cotswold-corniche-8mm-glass-walk-in-alcove-shower-enclosure

Was working fine yesterday, this Magento site seems to have a mind of it's own currently and is proving really frustrating - I've currently got none of our developers available today to help resolve this issue on a clients website.

Product options are not working
Quick zoom is not working
Add to cart is not working

Prototype.js errors

on page load

```
element.style is undefined
var value = element.style[style];
```

selecting a product option

```
element.tagName is undefined
var method = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
```

Not entirely sure if these js errors are the cause of these elements not working as I think I remember seeing them appearing in Firebug even when they were functioning correctly.

I thought it may be due to a prototype / jquery confliction but I can't even find a jquery library on the site or being referenced - so unsure whether a noconflict var is the solution. Possible confliction with a 3rd party extension maybe?

Would anyone be able to kindly take a look and see if you could easily identify the problem please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to resolve - as half suspected, was indeed a conflict between jquery and prototype.

Fixed by downloading jquery library - stored at js/jquery and added the following in page.xml

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</script></action>
```

Ensuring this is called before prototype/prototype.js

Fixed the issue instantly. Phew!

Comment: Ha, I knew it was prototype - jQuery conflict, just by reading the question title! :D You should accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When did the Silktide cookie script go on??  I just tried to look at the site and it took ages, then it loaded without any of the stylesheets.  The Cookie js ran, I dismissed it, refreshed and the site loaded up.  I would get rid of that first and see how things after that, it is loading in the latest jquery from the googleapis url - the call is in plugin.min.js

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Managed to fix it. Will answer with fix. :)